# it usually starts now or it is usually starting now

Tags: present-continuous, present-simple

what´s right? Use present simple or present continues.

**It usually starts now or It is usually starting now?**

Thank you

Comment: The principal meanings of the simple present are timeless and habitual. With _usually_, this is habitual, so the simple present is nearly always appropriate. I have noticed that Indian English does seem to use the continuous here, but not any other English that I am aware of.

Answer (score 1):

One way the present simple tense (or even the past simple tense, for that matter) is most often used is to describe actions that are habitual. Habitual actions are actions that happen at more or less regular intervals typically over a relatively long period of time. And there are adverbs that are used specifically for habitual actions. The adverb *usually* is certainly one of them. I don't think it's all that common to use *usually* with continuous tenses, but definitely possible in certain situations (e.g. *He is usually working at this time of day. So, he is probably not home right now.*). So, if *usually* is to be used and little to no context is provided, then, I'd say, it almost automatically necessitates the use of the present simple tense (or the past simple tense, depending on the situation). Therefore, out of your two examples, the first one sounds more like a natural choice (the other one sounds a bit odd):

> It usually starts now.

Though, to tell you the truth, I'm not sure what that actually would mean.